# send a row from a listview saved in database sqlite to another listview and make it do the same as the row in the first listview

Tags: android, string, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-database

i have two activities each one of them have a listview the first one is connected to a data base and get its data from strings.xml i want to send a row to the other listview in the aother activity and make it do the same as if it was in the first list view i did that before but all the data was saved in the database directly (no strnigs.xml) here is my code please help me

```
public class DB_Sqlite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String BDname = "data.db";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1; /*<<<<< ADDED BUT NOT NEEDED */
    public static final String TABLE_FAVOURITES = "mytable";

    public static final String FAVOURITES_COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID; /*<<<< use the Android stock ID name*/
    public static final String FAVOURITES_COL_NAME = "name";
    public static final String FAVOURITES_COL_FAVOURITEFLAG = "favourite_flag"; /*<<<<< NEW COLUMN */

    public DB_Sqlite(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, BDname, null, DBVERSION /*<<<<< used constant above */);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_FAVOURITES + " (" +
                FAVOURITES_COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + /*<<<<< AUTOINCREMENT NOT NEEDED AND IS INEFFICIENT */
                FAVOURITES_COL_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                FAVOURITES_COL_FAVOURITEFLAG + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0" + /*<<<<< COLUMN ADDED */
                ")");
        /* CHANGES HERE BELOW loop adding all Resource names NOT VALUES */
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        for (String s: StringResourcesHandling.getAllStringResourceNames()) {
            cv.clear();
            cv.put(FAVOURITES_COL_NAME,s);
            db.insert(TABLE_FAVOURITES,null,cv);


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_FAVOURITES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public boolean insertData(String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(FAVOURITES_COL_NAME, name);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_FAVOURITES,null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }


    public Cursor getFavouriteRows(boolean favourites)  {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String whereclause = FAVOURITES_COL_FAVOURITEFLAG + "=?";
        String compare = "<1";
        if (favourites) {
            compare =">0";
        }

        return db.query(
                TABLE_FAVOURITES,null,
                FAVOURITES_COL_FAVOURITEFLAG + compare,
                null,null,null,null
        );
    }


    private int setFavourite(long id, boolean favourite_flag) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String whereclause = FAVOURITES_COL_ID + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(FAVOURITES_COL_FAVOURITEFLAG,favourite_flag);
        return db.update(TABLE_FAVOURITES,cv,whereclause,whereargs);
    }


    public int setAsFavourite(long id) {
        return setFavourite(id,true);
    }


    public int setAsNotFavourite(long id) {
        return setFavourite(id, false);
    }

    /* Getting everything and make MatrixCursor VALUES from Resource names from Cursor with Resource names  */
    public Cursor getAllDataInCurrentLocale(Context context) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_FAVOURITES,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        if (csr.getCount() < 1) return csr;
        MatrixCursor mxcsr = new MatrixCursor(csr.getColumnNames(),csr.getCount());
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            mxcsr.addRow(convertCursorRow(context,csr,new String[]{FAVOURITES_COL_NAME}));
        }
        csr.close();
        return mxcsr;
    }
    public Cursor getDataInCurrentLocaleById(Context context, long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String wherepart = FAVOURITES_COL_ID + "=?";
        String[] args = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_FAVOURITES,null,wherepart,args,null,null,null);
        if (csr.getCount() < 1) return csr;
        MatrixCursor mxcsr = new MatrixCursor(csr.getColumnNames(),csr.getCount());
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            mxcsr.addRow(convertCursorRow(context,csr,new String[]{FAVOURITES_COL_NAME}));
        }
        csr.close();
        return mxcsr;
    }

    /* This getting columns from Cursor into String array (no BLOB handleing)*/
    private String[] convertCursorRow(Context context, Cursor csr, String[] columnsToConvert) {
        String[] rv = new String[csr.getColumnCount()];
        for (String s: csr.getColumnNames()) {
            boolean converted = false;
            for (String ctc: columnsToConvert) {
                if (csr.getType(csr.getColumnIndex(s)) == Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB) {
                    //........ would have to handle BLOB here if needed (another question if needed)
                }
                if (ctc.equals(s)) {
                    rv[csr.getColumnIndex(s)] = StringResourcesHandling.getStringByName(context,csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(s)));
                    converted = true;
                }
            } if (!converted) {
                rv[csr.getColumnIndex(s)] = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(s));
            }
        }
        return rv;
    }

    }
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DB_Sqlite dbSqlite;
    ListView listView;
    ListView listView1;
    ArrayAdapter adapter, adapter1;
    ArrayList arrayList, arrayList1;
    String[] number;
    Button button;
    StringResourcesHandling srh;
    MatrixCursor getAllDataInCurrentLocale,getAllDataInCurrentLocale1;
    SimpleCursorAdapter favourites_adapter,non_favourites_adapter;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, cc.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });





        /* Show the resources for demo */
        for (String s : StringResourcesHandling.getAllStringResourceNames()) {
            Log.d("RESOURCEDATA", "String Resource Name = " + s +
                    "\n\tValue = " + StringResourcesHandling.getStringByName(this, s)

            );

        }

        dbSqlite = new DB_Sqlite(this);
        Cursor csr = dbSqlite.getAllDataInCurrentLocale(this);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        csr.close();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getAllDataInCurrentLocale.close();

    }





    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        manageNonFavouritesListView();


    }





    private void manageNonFavouritesListView() {
        getAllDataInCurrentLocale = (MatrixCursor) dbSqlite.getAllDataInCurrentLocale(this);
        if (non_favourites_adapter == null) {
            non_favourites_adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    R.layout.textview,
                    getAllDataInCurrentLocale,
                    new String[]{FAVOURITES_COL_NAME},
                    new int[]{R.id.textview10},
                    0
            );
            listView.setAdapter(non_favourites_adapter);
            setListViewHandler(listView,false);
        } else {
            non_favourites_adapter.swapCursor(getAllDataInCurrentLocale);
        }
    }





    private void setListViewHandler(ListView listView, boolean favourite_flag) {
        if (!favourite_flag) {
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, tc.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
            listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,cc.class);
                    intent.putExtra("EXTRAKEY_ID",l);
                    String name = getAllDataInCurrentLocale.getString(getAllDataInCurrentLocale.getColumnIndex(FAVOURITES_COL_NAME));
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, name+" Added To Favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });

        }}


}
```

```
public class cc extends AppCompatActivity {
    String fav_name;
    long fav_id;
    DB_Sqlite dbSqlite;
    Cursor getAllDataInCurrentLocale, getDataInCurrentLocaleById;
    SimpleCursorAdapter non_favourites_adapter;
    ListView listView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cc);


        fav_id = getIntent().getLongExtra("EXTRAKEY_ID", 0);
        if (fav_id == 0) {
        }

        dbSqlite = new DB_Sqlite(this);
        Cursor cursor = dbSqlite.getDataInCurrentLocaleById(this, fav_id);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            fav_name = cursor.getString(getAllDataInCurrentLocale.getColumnIndex(FAVOURITES_COL_NAME));
            manageNonFavouritesListView();

        }
        cursor.close();
    }








    private void manageNonFavouritesListView() {
        getDataInCurrentLocaleById =  dbSqlite.getDataInCurrentLocaleById(this,fav_id);
        if (non_favourites_adapter == null) {
            non_favourites_adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    R.layout.textview,
                    getDataInCurrentLocaleById,
                    new String[]{FAVOURITES_COL_NAME},
                    new int[]{R.id.textview10},
                    0
            );
            listView1.setAdapter(non_favourites_adapter);
            setListViewHandler(listView1,false);
        } else {
            non_favourites_adapter.swapCursor(getDataInCurrentLocaleById);
        }
    }

    private void setListViewHandler(ListView listView1, boolean b) {

            listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(cc.this, tc.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });


        }

        }
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the id which is **`l`** of onItemClick call (# 4 value), add this as Extra to intent value then goes to the **cc** activity.

Like example to send is

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    if (i == 0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, cc.class);
        intent.putExtra("EXTRAKEY_ID",l); // THIS ADDED
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

You get id in **cc** activity with like

```
fav_id = getIntent().getLongExtra("EXTRAKEY_ID",0);
if (fav_id == 0) {
    .... code for not correct id
}
Cursor cursror = dbSqlite.getDataInCurrentLocaleById(this,fav_id);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    fav_name = cursor.getString(getAllDataInCurrentLocale.getColumnIndex(FAVOURITES_COL_NAME));
}
cursor.close();
```

- Above is after setting up **fav_id** (long) and **fav_name** (String) and dbSQlite (instance of DB_Sqlite like  `dbSqlite = new DB_Sqlite(this);`)

In DB_Sqlite.java you have method **getDataInCurrentLocaleById** like

```
public Cursor getDataInCurrentLocaleById(Context context, long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String wherepart = FAVOURITES_COL_ID + "=?";
    String[] args = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
    Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_FAVOURITES,null,wherepart,args,null,null,null);
    if (csr.getCount() < 1) return csr;
    MatrixCursor mxcsr = new MatrixCursor(csr.getColumnNames(),csr.getCount());
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        mxcsr.addRow(convertCursorRow(context,csr,new String[]{FAVOURITES_COL_NAME}));
    }
    csr.close();
    return mxcsr;
}
```